# 403/307 error in azure data factory pipeline execution

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

We need to implement transformation in azure while copying file from azure blob storage to azure data lake gen2. In the current implementation we are trying to achieve it using data flow in data factory. We have then embedded the data flow block in pipeline for execution. During execution it intermittently but most times fails with below error. While monitoring the debug data flow is seen as complete but the file is not copied.Also have attached the screenshot from the data factory debug window. Please advise me on this further to get this issue resolved.

Error Message:

```
{"message":"at Sink 'sink1': java.lang.Exception: Fail to reach https://eu.frontend.clouddatahub.net/subscriptions/4ce3448b-6b04-43ab-a4c4-9fa36dfb3bfb/authservice/ams/api/v2/acquiretoken with status code:403, payload:{\"ErrorCode\":307,\"Message\":\"ErrorCode : AuthSasRevoked, InnerException : null, ServiceTrace : \",\"ServiceStackTrace\":\"\"}, CorrelationId:2f7f8529-a6fe-4a79-a3ea-952d9213a727, RunId:3679a5bd-eeaa-418b-8d98-be63c116ddd8. Details:at Sink 'sink1': java.lang.Exception: Fail to reach https://eu.frontend.clouddatahub.net/subscriptions/4ce3448b-6b04-43ab-a4c4-9fa36dfb3bfb/authservice/ams/api/v2/acquiretoken with status code:403, payload:{\"ErrorCode\":307,\"Message\":\"ErrorCode : AuthSasRevoked, InnerException : null, ServiceTrace : \",\"ServiceStackTrace\":\"\"}, CorrelationId:2f7f8529-a6fe-4a79-a3ea-952d9213a727, RunId:3679a5bd-eeaa-418b-8d98-be63c116ddd8","failureType":"UserError","target":"data_flow_raw_storage_to_adls_transformation","errorCode":"DFExecutorUserError"}
```

Debug record:

[Debug View for Data Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0IQV.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a product bug with the Azure Data Flows. And the product bug has been fixed.